# Need javascript to auto-scroll to the target html element after page loads

Tags: javascript

I'm backend developer, new to javascript. Can anyone provide a few lines of script that will allow the page to auto-scroll to the "target" element after the page loads

```
<html>
<bod>

<p id="target">...</p> // auto-scroll here

</bod>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please mark a correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use scrollIntoView on the element in window.onload event..

In your case you would be doing:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('target');
    el.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Good docs can be found here:
[MDN scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 4):

Also change your body tag to something like

```
<body onload="ScrollToTarget">
```

Then your function can be defined in the header as

```
function ScrollToTarget()
{
     document.getElementById("target").scrollIntoView(true);
}
```